How to create link to job log for custom GitLab badge?
I created a GitLab badge that shows the test coverage using following "Badge image URL":
https://gitlab.cc-asp.{foo}.de/%{project_path}/badges/%{default_branch}/coverage.svg


If a user clicks on the badge, I would like to redirect to the corresponding job log:
https://gitlab.cc-asp.{foo}.de/%{project_path}/-/jobs/5938396


However, there does not seem to be a placeholder %{job_id} available to replace 5938396 in a generic way.

The following placeholders are available:

%{project_path}: Path of a project including the parent groups
%{project_title}: Title of a project
%{project_name}: Name of a project
%{project_id}: Database ID associated with a project
%{default_branch}: Default branch name configured for a project’s repository
%{commit_sha}: ID of the most recent commit to the default branch of a project’s repository


How can I define the dynamic URL to the job log in the GitLab settings for the badge?
Maybe there is an alternative syntax for the URL, something with a query parameter like:
?job=job_test

or a non-documented placeholder for the job id?
Edit:
If I use a format like
https://gitlab.cc-asp.{foo}.de/%{project_path}/-/jobs/artifacts/%{default_branch}/file/pytest/index.html?job=job_test

I am redirected to
https://gitlab.cc-asp.{foo}.de/%{project_path}/-/jobs/5938865/artifacts/external_file/pytest/index.html

Therefore, there does seem to be a way to auto-generate the required id 5938865 in the URL. However, I do not understand how it works and how to apply it to redirect to the wanted log URL.

